# copy data using scriptella based on a test on special column

Tags: scriptella

I have two databases in postgresql. I want to copy data from database to another based on a condition.I used scriptella but what i want is to copy rows when a column is not empty.But i always have the empty ones which are copied here what i did , i want to copy based on condition on a special column .
Here is the file

```
 <!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
    <etl>
        <description>
               test script
        </description>
                        <connection id="in" driver="postgresql"  url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testMonoprix" user="postgres" password="maher" >

                        </connection>

                        <connection id="out" driver="postgresql" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testMonoprix2" user="postgres" password="maher">

                        </connection>

        <query connection-id="in" >
                 SELECT * FROM public.param_type;
                <script connection-id="out" if=" parent_param_type_id != null ">

                        INSERT INTO public.param_type VALUES (?1, ?2,?3,?4,?5,?6)    ;          
                </script>
        </query>

    </etl>
```

How would the file be in order to copy non empty ones , 
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to copy based on parent_param_type_id not being empty? What is the type of this column?

Comment: hello , sorry for the delay i would like to test whether it is numeric or not in order to insert *